# Execution time exceeds

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to store an array of fetched data into a session, with the code below, but when i try to execute it, the execution time exceeds 30 seconds and it fails.
I can't seem to spot the error, so i'm hoping for a helping hand.

```
public function stat_query($user_id = null) 
{
$query = $this->core->conn->query("SELECT user_stats.value as value, stats.shortname as shortname FROM user_stats  INNER JOIN stats ON user_stats.stat_id = stats.id WHERE user_stats.user_id = ".$this->get_user($user_id));
$value = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
return $value;
}

public function init_stat_array($user_id = null){
    while($query = $this->stat_query($this->get_user($user_id))) {
        $this->temp_array[$query['shortname']] = $query['value'];
    }
}

public function store_session($user_id = null) {
    $this->init_stat_array($this->get_user($user_id));
    $_SESSION['stats'] = $this->temp_array;
}
```

Note: the the get_user function works as intended, it just returns the user that was bound in the constructor, or the inputted user.

Comment: if the user id exists in your database it will be an inifinite loop

Comment: `while($query = $this->stat_query($this->get_user($user_id))) {` This looks like a query being executed over and over infinitely in a loop. As long as a row is returned the loop continues forever.  What is contained in `$query` when the call completes?

Comment: You mean `foreach($this->stat_query(...) as $row)` instead of while I guess

Comment: *facepalm* Of course i need foreach.

Comment: You are running the same query over and over, with the same data. if it was successful the first time, it will be successful every time. `stat_query` always returns a truthy value

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. It's certainly getting late, and i'm not seeing straight anymore :D

Comment: Why do you need all these functions?

Comment: `stat_query` seems like it probably shouldn't be a public method. giving raw database rows seems like a leaky abstraction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The while loop does not work this way. Using while on `fetch_assoc` like `while ($row = $this->core->conn->fetch()` works because the `fetch` method is intended to work this way. Once you assign the return value of the fetch method to a variable (or method return value), runing `while()` on it won't work as running `while()` on fetch method, but as running `while()` on your method. So `while($this->yourMethod($value))` is always true if the method return non-false value when passing $value to it.

If a method return an array, then while is an overkill, because you will need to use `key()` and some other function to interact with arrays. In you case you need `foreach()`:

```
public function init_stat_array($user_id = null){
    foreach($this->stat_query($this->get_user($user_id)) as $row) {
        $this->temp_array[$row['shortname']] = $row['value'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`stat_query` starts the query and fetches the first row.  It will run indefinitely because it should return a truthy result with the `$this->get_user($user_id)` argument, and that argument does not change.  The simplest way to fix this would be to just remove the `while`, since that query should only return a single row anyway (I assume that the user_id is canonical).

You could also return the result set (`$query`) from that method and iterate over it in another method.  You would just have to call `fetch` externally.

I think that what you may want to loop over is `init_stat_array` since it would make sense to run `stat_query` for an array of user_ids.